# Tombstones in hash tables

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, tombstone

I am writing a class for a hash table. The hash table is an array of objects from a class I wrote, called `HashVariable`. The `HashVariable` has only two properties, a name, and a integer value. I know that if I delete an item from the table I will have to replace it with a 'tombstone' but I'm not sure what I should be using as a tombstone.

I haven't really tried much as I'm not sure what I could do. I could try to cast a character to `HashVariable` and insert it into the array but I can't cast it like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways that you could do this, depending on what is allowed to be stored in your table.

- If your table does not allow for `null` objects, then you could use a `null` object to mark a slot that's free, then have the associated integer take on different values based on why the slot is empty (for example, 0 means "was never filled," 1 means "tombstone", etc.)
- If your table does allow for `null` objects, you could special-case `null` as a key and store `null` separately from the rest of the hash table (say, have dedicated fields of the class corresponding to whether `null` is a key, and, if so, what value is associated with it). You could then use the above technique to mark empty table slots.
- If your table does not allow for negative keys, then you could use negative keys to mark empty slots (maybe, for example, -1 means "this slot is empty," and -2 means "this is a tombstone.")
- If your table allows for arbitrary keys and values, then you could add in parallel arrays of booleans (or an array of integers that works as a bitvector, which is more space-efficient) to mark which slots are empty and which slots are tombstones.
- If you're okay with a level of indirection, you could have each table slot be a pointer to an object that represents information about the slot. You could have some base class type (say, `HashSlot`) with two subclasses (say, `Tombstone` and `Entry`), where `Tombstone` just marks a tombstone slot and `Entry` actually stores the key/value pair.

This isn't an exhaustive list of options. As you can tell, there are lot of strategies you could use here! See which of these looks best-suited to your particular setup.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since the "HashVariable" is a class you have written you can have a boolean variable to mark the HashVariable as tombstone ( apart from having a name and value). For an example implementation take a look [here](https://github.com/JohnKurlak/HashTable/blob/master/HashTable.java).